# Nginx: Redirect search 301

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx

I'm using **nginx** and i found in my panel multiple **404 errors** for searches, because i migrated joomla to wordpress.

I need make a **rewrite** in nginx but i need help to do..

Eg:

**404 URL:**

```
http://example.com/component/search/?searchword=shoes&ordering=&searchphrase=all

http://example.com/component/content/?view=featured&start=220
```

**Would be:**

```
http://example.com/?s=shoes
http://example.com
```

**Nginx:**

```
server {

     #Other server configs...
     rewrite ^component/search/?searchword=$ http://example.com/?s= permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the URIs `/component/search/` and `/component/content/` are unique to the previous implementation, setting up two *prefix locations* may be the most efficient solution:

```
location /component/search/ {
    return 301 $scheme://$host/?s=$arg_searchword;

location /component/content/ {
    return 301 $scheme://$host/;
}
```

Comment: Thx, Richard! Works!